# How to handle class imbalance of multiple columns?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

My dataset is :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKifz.png). First seven columns are for input metric. And the last five columns are for outputs. Output is an array of 5 numbers consist of zero or one. I am using Keras functional API for that. Whenever I try to to resample my data with individual columns, I got shape issues in merging, even if I I try to slice the rows.

Comment: You can use [Stratified K-Fold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) when splitting the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there's no "easy" approach to doing this. The only logical way is to maybe use [Label Powerset](http://scikit.ml/api/skmultilearn.problem_transform.lp.html#skmultilearn.problem_transform.LabelPowerset) over your design matrix, and resample based on the created column off that - though in that scenario it might be easier to "handcraft" such a transformation.

Here is one approach

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler
import pandas as pd


X0, y = make_classification()
_, X1 = make_multilabel_classification(n_classes=5, random_state=0)

# transform X1 by creating a powerset...
df_x1 = pd.DataFrame(X1, columns=[f'c{x}' for x in range(X1.shape[1])])
df_x1 = pd.merge(df_x1, df_x1.drop_duplicates().reset_index()).rename(columns={"index":"dummy"})
print(df_x1['dummy'].value_counts())  # shows imbalance
df_x1 = df_x1.reset_index()  # so that we know which rows are resampled
df_y1 = df_x1['dummy']
df_x1 = df_x1[[x for x in df_x1.columns if x != 'dummy']]

ros = RandomOverSampler()
X_sample, _ = ros.fit_resample(df_x1, df_y1)  # this is the resampled index

X = np.hstack([X0, X1])
X_res, y_res = X[X_sample['index'], :], y[X_sample['index']]
```

Where the secret sauce really is this bit:

```py
df_x1 = pd.merge(df_x1, df_x1.drop_duplicates().reset_index()).rename(columns={"index":"dummy"})
```

Which re-indexes based on the selected 5 columns

```py
df_x1 = df_x1.reset_index()
```

Which is then used in the `RandomOverSampler`, and would guarantee the 5 columns would be balanced.

Finally, we can select the indices of the sampling, to generate a dataset and labels which has been successfully resampled across both `X0, X1, y`

```
X = np.hstack([X0, X1])
X_res, y_res = X[X_sample['index'], :], y[X_sample['index']]
```

Comment: Hi chappers, I am afraid I don't understand your solution. Let me clear my problem to you. I am editing my question.